What is a Moving Average Model (Really!)
I've been trying for some time now to understand what a moving average model is in a time series context.
I know that it is essentially a regression based on past forecast errors in the form indicated here: https://otexts.com/fpp3/MA.html (see 3rd line in this article).
What I find hard to understand is - what exactly are these past forecast errors?  Or more specifically, what is the nature of the forecast element in these past forecast errors?  Is it, for example, simply the moving average of the target time series up to a given point?  Or something else?

Hi: The forecast errors are how off the original model is ( when we don't include the current error term in the model ).
For example, suppose you had an ARMA(1,1) ? So, you have $y_t = \phi y_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1}$.  Then, $\epsilon_{t} = y_{t} - \phi y_{t-1} - \theta \epsilon_{t-1}$ where $\epsilon_{t-1}$ is the previous error term.
But what is $\epsilon_{t-1}$ ? Obviously, we don't have $\epsilon_{t-1}$. But, we can estimate it using $\hat{\epsilon}_{t-1}$ and use that as the estimate
at time $t$. So, at each time $t$, we have estimates of previous $\epsilon_{t}$ which are the previous $\hat{\epsilon}_t$.
Does that make sense ? I'm leaving some  of the more gory details out
but that's what they are by definition. They have other uses but they are needed when constructing a likelihood for the model parameters from which they are being constructed.
I always recommend Harvey's "Economic Analysis of Time Series" for a much more detailed explanation of my minimized answer.
It's a really nice book for this sort of question ( your question's answer really is Harvey's text.).  The likelihood construction details are obviously in time-series papers also but Harvey's text is the only time-series text I know of ( if there are others, I'm all ears. I don't stay as current as I'd like )  that goes into readable depth on the areas of error construction, likelihood construction, parameter estimation etc. Hamilton goes into good depth on some specific likelihood issues but Harvey's attack is more general and just worked
for me, eventually. He's not an easy read. I've read some sections of his various books multiple (much more than two ) times before it sank in.
One more thing: The use of the term "forecast errors"
is very tricky and confusing which is why your question is good.
It has to do with the fact that time-series shows up in so many
different fields. For example, some people use "forecast errors" (time-series-arima community), some use "error term" (macro-econometricians), some use "noise term" (DSP), some use "shock" (economists), some use "input noise" (control).
Whatever name is used, it is always referring to $\epsilon_t$ in the DGP. I'm not thrilled with "forecast errors" because that kind of implies that there is some forecasting going on which is only half true. I like "model error term at time t" but that's not popular
like the other ones.
